# Signed Request empty for some users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a strange problem with my Facebook Tab app.

I'm trying to know if some user like my page or not.

When I start my app, no problems, I get my `signed_request` filled.

But some of my users get their `signed_request` empty and I don't know why.

I used Facebook PHP SDK to decode my `signed_request`.

```
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'appId',
  'secret' => 'appSecret',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

I don't have any user restriction on my app and there are not redirection on my Page Tab URL.

Did I miss something?

Comment: So I finaly get the problem.
My friend don't have activate the "Secure Browsing" option, so he redirected on my "Page Tab URL" (and not the Secure Page Tab URL) but my server redirect any http connection to an https connection so I lost my signed_request ...

There is a way to avoid that or i'm required to configure my server for it does not redirect http connections ?

Comment: Can you please show how you did it? Reagrds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect request from http to https using 307 instead of 301. Which will keep the post data persist for next request too.

FYI: [307](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.8)

Comment: Yes, but the user will be prompted. "If the 307 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued."